# mail don't send i Want to send mail without using authentication the username and password

Tags: php

when want to send the mail without Authentication the username and password when is run this file i show a error message can anyone solve this problem. Here i am using PHPMailer and for Hosting server i use gmail smtp server.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$msg = 'Dear Sir,   <br><br>

This is reference to the candidate who has been shortlisted and Here we Enclose Rate/Month For the Candidate  <br><br>';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('testsmtpserverekennistest@gmail.com', 'Anurag Test');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('sinha.anurag.884@gmail.com', 'John Doe');

$mail->Body = $msg;

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP without auth test';

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain gmail does not allow sending of mail without authentication. For future reference. If you have the error message, include it in the question.

Comment: Even if gmail allowed sending emails with no authentication (which, btw, it does not), why would you want to do that? If you're at least a little bit concerned about deliverability you should at least use servers that require authentication (they tend to be a little bit more trusted by recipients) or even consider using a third party mail delivery service